# sql: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
select 
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01 ',
             concat((select concat((CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),102)),' ','12:00:01 AM')),'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s%p'))
```

Having problem while using `concat` in SQL Server. Getting error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: please post your output

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You're building a string like `'2016.02.10 12:00:01 AM%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s%p'` and then trying to use that as a parameter to `DATEDIFF`? Unsurprisingly, that's not convertible to a date. What's with all the `%m/%d` stuff?

Comment: and why is there a select in it?

Comment: remove '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s%p' then it will show difference

Comment: Trying to change mysql to sql,  query :select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE((select concat(date_format(now(),'%m/%d/%Y'),' ','06:00:00 AM')),'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s%p'))

Comment: select DATEDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01',((select concat((CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),102)),' ','12:00:01 AM'))))

Comment: here is the out put :1455042601

Comment: ok its working fine, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01 ',
        (SELECT CONCAT(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 102),' ','12:00:01 AM')))
```

You don't need the first concat statement and the datetime formatting at the end